# How can I implement Jordan's totient function?

Tags: number-theory

How can I implement [Jordan's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function)? It is a generalization of Euler's Phi function.

Comment: Well, you have the definition on hand. What have you tried so far to implement it?

Comment: See [Totient Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) you can download an file [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/NumberTheoreticFunctions/TotientFunction.nb)

Answer (score 8):

Mathematica code given by [Enrique Pérez Herrero](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Enrique_P%C3%A9rez_Herrero) at [OEIS A007434](https://oeis.org/A007434)

```
Clear[jordanTotient]

jordanTotient[n_, k_: 1] := 
  DivisorSum[n, #^k*MoebiusMu[n/#] &] /; (n > 0) && IntegerQ[n];
```

This could also be written as

```
Clear[jordanTotient]

jordanTotient[n_Integer?Positive, k_: 1] := 
  DivisorSum[n, #^k*MoebiusMu[n/#] &];
```

For k=1 this is [Euler totient function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerPhi.html)

```
And @@ (jordanTotient[#] == EulerPhi[#] & /@ Range[100])

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: This is wrong for $k=1$?

Comment: @ElRafu - Why do you say this? Please elaborate.

Comment: Apologies, I was mixing up the arguments!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a copy + paste from my `init.m` file:

```
JordanTotient[1, n_] := EulerPhi[n]

JordanTotient[_, 0] = 0;

JordanTotient[_, -1|1] = 1;

JordanTotient[k_, n_Integer] := 
  With[{pdiv = PrimeDivisors[n]},
    Abs[n]^k Product[1 - 1/p^k, {p, pdiv}] /; ListQ[pdiv]
  ]

JordanTotient /: MakeBoxes[JordanTotient[k_, n_], TraditionalForm] := 
  MakeBoxes[Subscript[J, k][n], TraditionalForm]

(* utilities *)

Options[PrimeDivisors] = Options[FactorInteger];

PrimeDivisors[n_, ops___] := 
  Block[{ps = FactorInteger[n, ops]},
    (
      ps = ps[[All, 1]];
      If[Abs[First[ps]] > 1, ps, Rest[ps]]

    ) /; ListQ[ps]
  ]
```

The `TraditionalForm` formatting could be improved.